# enum as storage?

Tags: java, enums

I have a large enum declared in my class

```
public enum CarMaker{
        Honda,
        Toyota,
        Sony,
        ...;

        public CarMaker at(int index){ //a method to retrieve enum by index
                CarMaker[] retval = this.values();
                return retval[index];
        }
        public final SomeObj val; //a value associated with each enum
            //.. more custom functions if needed
    }
```

since only one instance of each CarMaker is needed, is it a bad practice if I want to use this enum as a storage (like an array but instead access each element using indices, I could use more intuitive names. Also I can have custom functions for each element)

```
CarMaker A = CarMaker.Honda;
CarMaker B = CarMaker.at(1); 
//Error above b/c 'at' is not a static member, can I make at a static member?

A.val = 5; 
B.val = 6; 
//Here I want A to be share data with B since both are "Honda"
//but it doesn't seem to do that yet
 System.out.println(A)
 System.out.println(B)

//Expected output:
//A: 6
//B: 6
```

Right now A and B seem to create their own instance of "Honda", but I want them to be shared. Is it possible?

Comment: oops... but you get my idea. :P

Comment: Enums don't have separate instances, so I don't see how you're having your problem. A and B should be one and the same object.

Comment: (off-topic) Your `at(int index)` method can simply do: `return this.values()[index]` without the need for the intermediate variable.

Comment: No, I mean what does it do _exactly_? Please update your post to show the source code for the `output` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your enum but via composition: Create an enum of brand names, but then build your objects that need a name to hold a field of the enum.

Example

```
public enum CarMaker {
   Honda,
   Toyota,
   Sony,
   Olympus,
   Facebook,
   Google,
   ...
}

public class Car {
   CarMaker carMaker;
   //... etc....

   Car(CarMaker carMaker) {
      this.carMaker = carMaker;
      // ... more code
   }

   //....
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, do you mind giving me a quick example?

Comment: @YonkShi: I'm not sure what you mean by " is it a bad practice if I want to use this enum as a storage (like an array but instead access each element using indices, I could use more intuitive names", but perhaps you're looking at using an EnumMap?

Comment: @YonkShi: With an `EnumMap<CarMaker, Car> cars` you can do: `cars.get(CarMaker.HONDA).doSomething()` (as you describe in Jeffrey's comment section).

Answer (score 5):

`enum`s are supposed to be immutable constants. Giving them a public, modifiable field is a horrible idea.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I can't think of other ways to assign intuitive names to a group of custom objects. Too bad I can't overload [] operator in java. Otherwise I'd totally ditch enum.

Comment: @YonkShi *assign intuitive names to a group of custom objects* what do you mean?

Comment: @Jeffrey I mean that I have a group of Car Objects, each has a unique name (car maker in this case), my ideal solution would be `Car["Honda"].doSomething()`, `Car[2].doSomething()`.